# Duda sobre optimizacion de codigo de count en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

tengo diferentes count para mostrar la cantidad de datos guardados en una tabla, el problema es que tuve que hacer varios count en el controlador porque necesito que el contador me muestre los datos segun unos parametros especificos lo que causo que tuvieras que repetir el codigo varias veces lo cual no creo sea la mejor opcion, pero al ser novato usando laravel no se como optimizar los llamados asi que por favor si pueden darme algun consejo estaria muy agradecido.

Aqui un ejemplo del codigo:

```
//CONTADOR GENERAL DE CASOS
        $tipocasog=Caso::select('Casos.CodTipCaso')
            ->join('TipoCaso','Casos.CodTipCaso', '=', 'TipoCaso.CodTipCaso')
            ->count();
        //TIPO CASO:SALUD
        $tipocaso_s=Caso::select('Casos.CodTipCaso'/*,'TipoCaso.CodTipCaso','TipoCaso.DescTipCaso'*/)
            ->join('TipoCaso','Casos.CodTipCaso', '=', 'TipoCaso.CodTipCaso')
            ->where('TipoCaso.DescTipCaso', '=', 'Salud')
            ->count();
        //TIPO CASO:DENUNCIA
        $tipocaso_d=Caso::select('Casos.CodTipCaso'/*,'TipoCaso.CodTipCaso','TipoCaso.DescTipCaso'*/)
            ->join('TipoCaso','Casos.CodTipCaso', '=', 'TipoCaso.CodTipCaso')
            ->where('TipoCaso.DescTipCaso', '=', 'Denuncia')
            ->count();
        //TIPO CASO:ORIENTIACION
        $tipocaso_o=Caso::select('Casos.CodTipCaso'/*,'TipoCaso.CodTipCaso','TipoCaso.DescTipCaso'*/)
            ->join('TipoCaso','Casos.CodTipCaso', '=', 'TipoCaso.CodTipCaso')
            ->where('TipoCaso.DescTipCaso', '=', 'Orientación')
            ->count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtenerlos todos y agruparlos con where de las collections de Laravel

```
$tipocasog=Caso::select('Casos.CodTipCaso')
            ->join('TipoCaso', 'Casos.CodTipCaso', '=', 'TipoCaso.CodTipCaso')
            ->get();
//La siguiente linea la repites para cada caso
$tipocaso_s= $tipocasog->where('DescTipCaso', 'Salud')->count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Pudieras intentar hacerlo mediante **Query Scopes** del modo siguiente:

**En el modelo `Caso.php`** escribes:

```
public function scopeFiltroCaso($query, $condicion)
{
    return $query->where('TipoCaso.DescTipCaso', '=', $condicion);
}
```

Ahora a nivel de tu controlador puedes componer la consulta asi:

```
$valor = "aquielvalor";

$tipocaso_s=Caso::select('Casos.CodTipCaso')
                ->join('TipoCaso','Casos.CodTipCaso', '=', 'TipoCaso.CodTipCaso')
                ->filtroCaso($valor)
                ->count();
```

Donde:

- En lugar de usar de forma directa el método **`where`**, lo que hago es invocar el *query Scope* creado
- Como a parte del argumento **`$query`** le pasamos un segundo argumento llamado **`$condicion`** entonces aquí es donde tu consulta se vuelve dinámica y podrá recibir según la invoques el valor por el cual quieres componer el filtro de tu **`where`**

**Referencias**

- [local Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#local-scopes)

Comment: lo hice asi y no me trae los datos, use dd() para confirmar y el arreglo estaba vacio

Comment: ¿Cuál de los dos ejemplos usaste?

Comment: ambos, primero el que comento jonathan orta y luego el tuyo, y en el primero solo me enviaba el primer dato que recibia la variable y el 2do no me cargaba los datos, y lo cargue como lo tenia, y el problema es que debo filtrarlo por fecha en que se creo o mostrar los datos del mes actual por eso queria optimizar y reducir el query